# Recover Data from Windows Formatted External Hard Drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

I cannot boot my laptop into Windows anymore because of a RAM issue, and I want to access its data from another computer.

The HDD has 2 partitions `C: (system)` and `D:`, would I be able to access both partitions if I connected the HDD as an external hard drive to another computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the drive out of the laptop and plug it into another computer, externally or internally, the other computer will give the drive a new drive letter. (Not gonna be C:)

Once the drive is mounted you will see the exact same file structure as you had in your laptop. All you'd have to do is navigate through the drive to your desktop, documents, videos, pictures, ect. As the saying goes, Bob's your uncle, your data is now accessible.

All of this given it wasn't a bad hard drive to be the cause of the broken laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Depends **why** your laptop 
 "just stopped working suddenly."

If it was non-disk-related, the partitions (including ones you may not normally see, such as recovery, if any) should show up when mounted as an external on another system. They will have different drive letters, but should be easy to recognize by their contents.

If it stopped working because the disk died, you'll be on your way to learning why you should always have important stuff backed up in multiple locations.